# Laravel Project not found in https

Tags: php, laravel, apache, system-administration, ubuntu-17.10

I currently issued a SSL Certificate to my Ubuntu 17.01 server with Apache2. I tried to redirect HTTP to HTTPS but my Laravel Project now is not exist. but the Ubuntu Default Page works.

My SSL conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
            RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName  pdrrmo-bulacan.me
            ServerAlias www.pdrrmo-bulacan.me
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/pdrrmo-bulacan.me.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/pdrrmo-bulacan.me.key
            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

my laravel conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin einnar82@gmail.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pdrrmo-prod/public
 ServerName pdrrmo-bulacan.me
 ServerAlias www.pdrrmo-bulacan.me
 Redirect / https://pdrrmo-bulacan.me
 <Directory /var/www/html/pdrrmo-prod/>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` versus `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pdrrmo-prod/public`. Your configs point to totally different folders.

Comment: @ceejayoz before i configure my ssl, that config works.

Comment: Sure, because now you're redirecting HTTP to HTTPS, and your HTTPS config points as the wrong `DocumentRoot`. You should know what you're doing before muddling around in configs like this.

Comment: use https://certbot.eff.org, far simpler to setup ssl without complications

Comment: welcome @Rannie Ollit